# Variable isn't being set properly

Tags: c

The problem is with this for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++);
{
    a = y & 1;
    y = y >> 1;
    b = a | b;
    b = b << 1;
}
```

you see i have set n to 4 so the compiler should've went four times through the loop, but it only goes through once (I added a "printf" to print 'i' and it prints 4). Why is i being set to 4 instead of zero?

ps I'm using visual studio 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++);
                           ^
```

Extra semi-colon. Easy mistake to make.

Comment: Further explanation: the computer does nothing (`;`) four times, then does the stuff after the loop (which is the bitwise stuff).